# Show stock availability in Shopping Cart

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1

I am new to magento. I want to show stock availability in Shopping Cart. So that if user want to update quantity of items he/she knows how much stock is available for particular item.

I have read many tutorials but unable to find the solution as people is saying stock can't be shown for configurable products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is very simple.
Please add a  **Stock Status**  filed in **default\template\checkout\cart.phtml**

and go to **\default\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml**

```
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton(‘catalog/product’)->load($_item->getProductId()); ?>

<td class=”a-center”>
<span calss=”stock-cart”>  <?php
$qty = $_product->getStockItem()->getQty();
if($qty > 0){
echo “In stock”;
}else{
echo “Out of stock”;
}
?>
</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just added simply this code to the checkout\cart\item\default.phtml just below the h2 title and it works on 1.9

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>
<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?
```